# Spec sheet requires checksums, How should these be formatted?

Tags: audio, broadcasting

I'm doing some audio deliverables for a feature film's TV package. The spec sheet I'm working from says that all media has to be provided with an MD5 checksum.

I know how to compute MD5 checksums for files but is there a specific format for checksum's that's customary?  Could I use the MD5 feature of `mtree(1)`? Or do you do a $FILENAME.md5 for each file? Or something else?

Comment: The spec should include how they want to receive the checksums. There is no industry standard. If the spec didn't include it, I would contact the studio.

Comment: Can you give any examples of how you've done them in the past?

Comment: I never delivered to a destination that required it. I only know of one US broadcaster who asked for checksums and they required you use their software to package the files. I don't think DPP/AS-11 requires it and I couldn't find a requirement in Netflix's spec's for checksums, either.

Comment: @MichaelLiebman Thanks I consider this answer complete.

Comment: Glad to help. I put that all in to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard used by US broadcasters for how to format checksums. I've never delivered to a broadcaster that requires it, but I've mostly been involved in delivering commercials. [DPP/AS-11](http://amwa.tv/projects/AS-11.shtml) doesn't specify anything about checksums and neither does [Netflix](https://backlothelp.netflix.com/hc/en-us/categories/202282037-SPECIFICATIONS-GUIDES). I only know of one US broadcaster that does require checksums and they require using their proprietary software to build up the delivery package.